# I'm new to Ubuntu, and I'd like to know how the Firefox browser really works. Strange, after Windows System(s)....

Tags: firefox

Browsing with Firefox from the Ubuntu is very strange, especially the search bar.
Is it the only option, or I can create something different?

Comment: What have you been using before?

Comment: It is not clear what you mean by **very strange**. Could you edit your question and give some examples of this strangeness? It will be great if you could take screenshots and post them in your question.

Comment: @Tonio67 what are the differences between Firefox in Ubuntu and Firefox for Windows from your point of view?

Comment: For example, I tried to enter to a site, abundanthope.net, there is an intro, but the firefox wants to play it or save it, which wasn't there, when I used firefox with windows7. I tried to download the suggested player, but need some kind of code...

Comment: But it works for me. Have you installed restricted extras?

Comment: You need to install flash, open a terminal window (ctrl-alt-t) and type `sudo apt-get install flashplugin-installer`.

Comment: I tried to installing the restricted extras, but need to type some authentic key, to install any software... Yes, I realized, It's a totally new OS, needs to build up and install every apps...

Comment: @Tonio67 You needed to input your password. You should have created one during the installation.

Answer (score 1):

If you prefer, you don't need to use the search text field. If you just type in the address bar what you are looking for and press enter, if it doesn't appear to be an URL firefox will search using the default search engine (should be google, but you can [customize](http://www.firefoxfacts.com/2008/01/13/change-default-search-in-firefox/) it).

If you want to adjust the look and feel of firefox, just right click on a toolbar and select customize. For instance, you can remove the search field, if you prefer.

If you need any function that firefox does not come with, check out http://addons.mozilla.org - you can customize firefox in many ways, and it should be possible to get it very close to the look and feel you prefer.

If you don't like firefox, there are many alternative browsers available in the Ubuntu software repositories. One of them is chromium-browser, which is Google Chrome, without the non-free components. Another option is the Gnome Webbrowser, which is named epiphany-browser. Further alternatives are Midori, rekonq, konqueror, arora, dooble,...
If you add a custom software repository, you can also easily install [Opera Web Browser](https://help.ubuntu.com/community/OperaBrowser).

In case you have bad eyes, use a Braille terminal, or simply prefer a clean and high contrast display of web pages, there are text based browsers available, the most prominent ones are lynx, elinks and links. Graphical browsers which are small and fast, but have limited functionality are chimera2, netsurf and dillo.